# Is it possible to use a cmdlet as an input parameter for a dynamic PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

Here's a test script I'm trying to use, and I'm calling it from a separate process and attempting to pass parameters to it.  The idea is that I have a user interface that allows a user to select a CmdLet and then populate another dropdown with the properties/methods of that CmdLet.

My problem seems to be that the script is rendering the input parameter as a string, and is thusly creating a text file with the methods and properties of any arbitrary string to which you've applied a "Get-Member" to, such as "Clone", or "CompareTo".  The only property as such is "Length".

Is there any way to have that input parameter be brought over as a usable CmdLet instead of a string?  Perhaps I'm missing something, or perhaps what I'm attempting to do isn't possible.

```
param([string]$inputCmdLet = "Get-NetAdapter");

$wrkgDir = "D:\Distribution\Operational";

# Get Properties and Methods for CmdLet Input Parameter
$propertyNames = $inputCmdLet | Get-Member -MemberType Property;
$methodNames = $inputCmdLet | Get-Member -MemberType Method;

# Sort Arrays
$propertyNames = $propertyNames | Sort-Object Name;
$methodNames = $methodNames | Sort-Object Name;

# Output Results to Text Files
$propertyNames.Name | Out-File $wrkgDir\$inputCmdLet.Properties.txt;
$methodNames.Name | Out-File $wrkgDir\$inputCmdLet.Methods.txt;
```

**EDIT FOR MORE INFO:**

The output I'm hoping for, in the example of Get-NetAdapter, is the list of properties in one output file and methods in the other.  What I'm getting now is this:

[Left list is expected (partial) result, right list is actual result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6nVH.png)

I'm uncertain how to achieve the result list on the left (in the image) programmatically.  I'm able to get the proper output by typing it out statically:

```
$mbrNameStatic = Get-NetAdapter | Get-Member;
$mbrNameStatic.Name | Out-File $wrkgDir\$inputCmdLet.Strings.txt;
```

But when i use the input parameter, it merges the value in as a string, so it seems the actual runtime code looks more like this:

```
$propertyNames = "Get-NetAdapter" | Get-Member -MemberType Property;
```

So the addition of the quotes renders the cmdlet as a string (makes sense i suppose, since my input parameter is a string), which returns the properties and methods of a string instead of the cmdlet. Is there any way to have the cmdlet render out without the quotes?

Please do let me know if I'm not making sense with this, either with my description, or with the idea altogether.

Thanks!

Comment: What you describe is what the `Show-Command` cmdlet does. It displays a UI for a cmdlet. Is there a reason to rewrite a built-in cmdlet? Alternatively `Get-Command` can be used to retrieve an object that represents a given cmdlet, function, or script based on a name.

Comment: hi @mikez, thanks for the response.  the purpose i'm attempting to achieve is to leverage ease of use for users who aren't familiar with powershell or scripting at all.  the idea is to wrap this functionality into an existing multipurpose UI, but provide extensibility and reusable code.  how should I use the Get-Command in my case?  I tried this:

    param([string]$inputCmdLet = "Get-NetAdapter");

    $targetCmdLet = Get-Command $inputCmdLet;

  but alas, this did not get me the member properties and methods for the cmdlet that is input.  thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute a command whose *name* (only) is stored in a variable or whose name is specified in single or double quotes, you must use `&`, the *call operator*.

```
# WRONG: The token is interpreted as an *expression* that outputs a *string*
"Get-NetAdapter"  # outputs the [string] literal

# WRONG: ditto, via a variable
$name = "Get-NetAdapter"
$name  # outputs the contents of the [string] variable

# OK: Use of & tells Powershell to interpret the next token as a *command* to *invoke*.
& "Get-NetAdapter"
& $name
```

---

As for your general approach:

- Note that not all cmdlets produce output when invoked *without parameters*, so your current code (even with `&`) won't work with all cmdlets.
- Conversely, those cmdlets that do produce output when given no parameters may produce a *lot* of them, which is unnecessary, so consider something like `& $inputCmdlet | Select-Object -First 1`.
- Generically, you can use something like `(Get-Command Get-NetAdapter).OutputType` to obtain a cmdlet's output type(s), but note that:

  - Declaring output types is *optional*, so not all cmdlets may return a value.
  - If you start with a *type* rater than an *instance* of that type, you cannot use `Get-Member` to discover the *instance members* (you can only obtain the *static* members via `-Static`).

Comment: the ampersand did the trick.  this is still very much an idea taking shape, so i was expecting to run into caveats like you've described. I'm still new to powershell, and am lacking some of the basics such as this; i assumed it would probably be something simple with which i was yet unacquainted. much appreciated!